# iOS App Submission Binary Rejected (2.16) + UIBackgroundModes

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

My application was rejected because the use of the background, but the rare thing is that ins't haven't the UIBackgroundModes on the InfoAdditions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxxyd.png)

How is possible?

Itunes Report :

Your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but did not include features that require persistent audio.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try setting the info additions for UIBackgroundModes and leaving the array empty.

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
            <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
            <array>
            </array>
        ]]>
    </InfoAdditions>
</iPhone>
```

And set this in your AS3

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.executeInBackground = false;
```

Comment: How can be possible that the app includes something that isn't there ?
How can I check on my current binary the background audio key declaration on the Info.plist ???

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Do you include any third-party libraries, maybe cocoapods?  It could be that something you're including in your project is using background audio and the declaration is in their info.plist, not yours.

Comment: How can I check the info.plist for my app?

Answer (score 0):

I did tried without luck the app was reject again.I don't know what can be, because isn't included at all

```
<InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key> 
        <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string> 
        <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key> 
        <string>NO</string> 
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
        <array>
        </array>
       <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key><false/>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
```

Itunes description :

Your updated binary is still displaying the background audio key. For help with code level question please contact Developer Technical Support, the link can be found at the bottom of this email.

Your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but did not include features that require persistent audio.